# Slim framework flash and middleware

Tags: php, frameworks, slim, middleware

I'm learning how to use Slim Framework and I have a problem using flash message inside a custom middleware.

The problem is quite simple: I use the `$app->flash('error', 'my message');` in the middleware and there is no message in the next page.

The middleware works great by the way

Here is my code:

*Middleware*

```
class SessionMiddleware extends \Slim\Middleware {

    public function call() {

        $app = $this->app;
        $req = $app->request;


        if(!preg_match('#^(/public)#', $req->getPath())) {
            if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && !empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
                //Do something
            } else {
                $app->flash('error', 'You must be logged');
                if($req->getPath() != '/login') {
                    $app->redirect('/login');
                }
            }
        }

        $this->next->call();

    }

}
```

*Login*

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['slim.flash']['error'])) {
    echo '<p class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Error</strong>: '.$_SESSION['slim.flash']['error'].'</p>';
}
?>
```

*App*

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
  'mode' => 'development',
  'debug' => true,
  'templates.path' => './templates'
));

$app->add(new \SessionMiddleware());

$app->get('/login', function() use($app) {
  $app->render('login.php');
});
```

Any ideas how to fix that ?

Thank you

Comment: You should be aware that in the upcoming version 3, [flash messages are being removed](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/upgrade.html#flash-messages).

Comment: Are you starting the session, with `session_start`?

Comment: Yes Gustavo, I'm using a session_start(); on index.php

Comment: Thanks for the information alexw ! Maybe I should start learning Slim V3 so but I can't find find any nice docs :/

Comment: @Ashraam Here are the Slim V3 Docs: https://www.slimframework.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [flashNow](http://docs.slimframework.com/flash/overview/) instead of flash method.

Answer (score 0):

I also saw that 'flash' and 'flashNow' methods are not working in middleware. To add flash message, I decided to do it manually. It's working, but I know that's not the best approach.

```
$_SESSION['slim.flash']['error'] = 'message';
```

Answer (score 0):

Running into this issue myself.

Since Flash is an app middleware component and is added by default, and before you add any custom app middleware components, it won't actually be initialised when your middleware is called.

Doing what @kkochanski has done is hacky, but is probably the only option, short of removing/unsetting Flash and adding it as the final app middleware component.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing with the same problem and resolve it. You can achieve that with call another method in authenticated route and flashing inside it for example

```
class AuthController
{
  public function flashError($request, $response)
  {
    // flash
    // redirect
  }
}
```

It works well for me. So you can just redirect to and make sure this method handle it. So you can flashing message outside middleware.